# Scheduled Publish in Mass Transit

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm using Mass Transit with .NET Core 3.1 and Azure Service Bus.

I want to make use of Service Bus's Scheduled Delivery feature when publishing messages to a topic.  AZSB seems to support this just fine, but I'm having problems trying to get MT to do it's bit.

I have previously sent scheduled messages successfully to a queue, but want to move to using pub/sub instead.  This is the initial send, so not inside a consumer context.

I have now reached the point where I have 'schedule published' a message, it has the correct ScheduledTime attribute on the message, and the Message types is "urn:message:MassTransit.Scheduling:ScheduledMessage".

However, the messages go straight into the subscription for immediate delivery, instead of being scheduled within the topic.

Here is my code:

```
    private async Task<Result> PublishScheduledMessage(MyTask message, DateTime scheduledDelivery)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = await _bus.GetPublishSendEndpoint<MyTask>();
            await _bus.SchedulePublish<ScheduledMessage>(endpoint, scheduledDelivery, message);
            return Result.Success();
        }
        catch (MassTransitException e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e, $"Error while trying to send scheduled MyTask.  Exception: {e.Message}");
            return Result.Failure(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

(I also tried publishing MyTask type instead of ScheduledMessage, but no difference)

The only docs I could find on this were [here](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/azure-sb-scheduler.html).  However, the scheduler interface has no Publish interface, only send, so will only deliver to queues it seems?  Does SchedulePublish only work with Rabbit and Quartz?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, MassTransit v7 has `SchedulePublish` built into `IMessageScheduler`, so you can use that once you upgrade.

In the meantime, and because you're using Azure Service Bus, you can schedule a publish easily by just setting the `ScheduledEnqueueTime` when publishing, as shown below (using the extension method).

```
bus.Publish<MyTask>(message, context =>
    context.SetScheduledEnqueueTime(delay));
```

That will set the property for you, which will delay the message until the scheduled time. Basically, the same thing that the scheduler is doing.

When you're scheduling messages using Azure Service Bus (and not using Quartz or Hangfire), you don't use the ScheduleMessage types at all, those are only used for the external message schedulers.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Chris, will try this now!

Comment: Chris, compiler reports that ScheduledEnqueueTime is readonly - interface only appears to have a { get; } ?

Comment: I also tried adding the difference between utc now and by deliveryDate, but get an error - GreenPipes.PayloadNotFoundException: 'The payload was not found: MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.BrokeredMessageContext'.  I'm using injecting IBus into this class btw, it's not a consumer.

Comment: I edited the answer to show the correct interface, `ServiceBusSendContext`.

Comment: Working now thanks Chris - I'll fork the documentation repo and offer up a PR in case anyone else needs this.  Cheers!